# Low pressure in shower after water main restrictor installed; what are my options?

Tags: shower, water-pressure

Note: Lots of similar questions, but they mostly deal with either a *sudden, unexplained* drop in water pressure, or with water pressure that has *always* been low.

In my case, the situation is as follows:

- MIL's house had awesome showers with decent pressure.
- But, as it turns out, the main water pressure was too high and damaged some valves on the heater. A plumber came, fixed stuff, and installed pressure limiting device right at the main.
- There's no gauge at the water main so I don't know what it's set to, like 40 or 50 PSI?
- Now with that pressure limited, the showers in the house are pretty disappointing. I measured the flow rate on one of them and got something like 1.5 GPM, whereas the heads themselves should be rated for 2.5 GPM.

Now what can I do to enhance the shower experience again? Could it be that somewhere in the pipe that goes to the shower there's a pressure limiting device as well, which made sense back in the days of high main pressure but is overkill now that main pressure is limited?

Or is it that the heads that were meant for 2.5 GPM just are very disappointing when pressure is low and I should go and get a head that's *meant* for lower pressure like 1.5 GPM?

Comment: Perhaps the first step is to get that plumber back out to do the work correctly.  Perhaps he used a pressure limiter that has too small a flow rate.  Perhaps it wasn't install right.

Comment: Increased pressure equals higher flow, reduced pressure equals lower flow. Yes most shower heads do have restrictors in them and I remove them in my showers it helps if they are accessible. For the pressure to be damaging things the pressure normally would be over 80 psi and the normal recommendation is 60 so you may be experiencing a 20+ psi drop and that will drastically affect the flow nothing wrong there it is a basic pressure/flow issue.

Comment: Hi @EdBeal thank you for the answer. I bought a pressure gauge to hook up to an outside tap so I can check what the actual pressure is. There is one faucet in the house that runs at like 3 GPM so it seems flow _generally_ seems to be fine. I wonder if the showers were "calibrated" for the old pressure and could be recalibrated?

Comment: There are normally restrictors in the shower heads themselves they may have them in the faucet but I doubt that because a tub spigot doesn’t have a restriction. Usually they are at the entrance or behind a screen, I have removed some and drilled others out.